# getting complie error while assigning value to a String: String before_xpath="//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[";

Tags: selenium

I am getting complie error while assigning value to a String:

`String before_xpath="//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[";`

Java - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

Is there anything missing in this code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers.You have not included syntactically valid code. Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help  and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You can format the programm code in your question better with the grave accent character (`code`) or tripple ```, for multi-line code blocks

Answer (score 3):

1. For variable names use camelCase, so that name it like beforeXpath
2. Please note you have to mask double quotes in strings: `String beforeXpath="//*[@id=\"content\"]/table/tbody/tr[";`